# what is the exit condition of for loop?

Tags: c, loops, data-structures

My below program works fine, but I don't understand the use of `exp[i]` as a loop termination condition at the marked location.  Why and under what circumstances does this make the loop exit?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Stack type
struct Stack
{
   int top;
   unsigned capacity;
   int* array;
};

// Stack Operations
struct Stack* createStack( unsigned capacity )
{
   struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

   if (!stack) 
      return NULL;

   stack->top = -1;
   stack->capacity = capacity;

   stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));

   if (!stack->array)
      return NULL;
   return stack;
}

int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
   return stack->top == -1 ;
}

char peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
   return stack->array[stack->top];
}

char pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
   if (!isEmpty(stack))
      return stack->array[stack->top--] ;
   return '$';
}

void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
   stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
}


// A utility function to check if the given character is operand
int isOperand(char ch)
{
   return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}

// A utility function to return precedence of a given operator
// Higher returned value means higher precedence
int Prec(char ch)
{
   switch (ch)
   {
      case '+':
      case '-':
         return 1;

      case '*':
      case '/':
         return 2;

      case '^':
         return 3;
   }
return -1;
}


// The main function that converts given infix expression
// to postfix expression. 
int infixToPostfix(char* exp)
{
   int i, k;

   // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size 
   struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
   if(!stack) // See if stack was created successfully 
      return -1 ;
```

what is the exit condition of this below for loop?

```
for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i]; ++i) 
{
    // If the scanned character is an operand, add it to output.
    if (isOperand(exp[i]))
        exp[++k] = exp[i];

    // If the scanned character is an ‘(‘, push it to the stack.
    else if (exp[i] == '(')
        push(stack, exp[i]);

    // If the scanned character is an ‘)’, pop and output from the stack 
    // until an ‘(‘ is encountered.
    else if (exp[i] == ')')
    {
        while (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
            exp[++k] = pop(stack);
        if (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
            return -1; // invalid expression             
        else
            pop(stack);
    }
    else // an operator is encountered
    {
        while (!isEmpty(stack) && Prec(exp[i]) <= Prec(peek(stack)))
            exp[++k] = pop(stack);
        push(stack, exp[i]);
    }

}

// pop all the operators from the stack
while (!isEmpty(stack))
    exp[++k] = pop(stack );

exp[++k] = '\0';
printf( "%sn", exp );
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
   char exp[] = "a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i";
   infixToPostfix(exp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `exp[i]` is true, that is, its value is not the `\0` string terminator, the loop continues. The loop also has `return -1; // invalid expression`. Also the function does not return a value at its end. Please look at compiler warnings.

Comment: At that `return -1;` in the loop you will get a memory leak, and maybe something wrong with your stack management. There are probably many problems in the code, after understanding the loop condition. Is this your own code?

Answer (score 3):

The loop will continue as long as `exp[i]` evaluates to `true`.

`exp[i]`, without any other context, evaluates to `char`. A `char` can be used where a boolean value is expected. The boolean value will be `false` if the value of the `char` is `0` and  `true` otherwise.

In your usage, the loop will continue for every character of `exp` except the terminating null character. When the terminating null character is encountered, the loop will stop.

A more readable form would be to use `exp[i] != '\0'`.

```
for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i] != '\0'; ++i) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is    `exp[i]`

If you have a string terminator (`\0`), it evaluates to `false`. If it is another `char`, it evaluates to `true`, so we enter the loop.
If it is `\0` the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, exp[i] returns true until '\0' (null character) is hit. If there isn't a null character it will continue and likely overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To add more clarity to the code, we can do following changes to the above for loop:

```
int exp_length = strlen(exp);
for(i = 0, k = -1; i<exp_length; ++i) {

}
```

Both do the same thing. 
Basically, the middle expression in for loop is meant to evaluate the termination condition. The for loop continues as long as the middle expression is evaluated to be `true` and it breaks when middle expression is evaluated to be `false`.

- if `i = exp_length`, then condition `i<exp_length` evaluate false and for loop breaks.
- Similarly, last character `(at i = exp_length)` in exp string contains `null`,so condition `exp[i]` evaluate false and for loop breaks.